# Doxygen parsing ampersands for ascii chars

Tags: c++, ascii, doxygen

I've been using Doxygen to document my project but I've ran into some problems.

My documentation is written in a language which apostrophes are often used. Although my language config parameter is properly set, when Doxygen generates the HTML output, it can't parse apostrophes so the code is shown instead of the correct character.

So, in the HTML documentation:

- **This should be the text:** `Vector d'Individus`
- **But instead, it shows this:** `Vector d&#39;Individus`

That's strange, but searching the code in the HTML file, I found that what happens is that instead of using an ampersand to write the `&#39;` code, it uses the ampersand code. Well, seeing the code is easier to see:

```
<div class="ttdoc">Vector d&amp;#39;Individus ... </div>
```

One other thing is to note that this only happens with the text inside tooltips...

[image: Text in a Tooltip]

But not on other places (same code, same class)...

[image: Text on another place]

What can I do to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried posting to the Doxygen forums or newsgroups?

Comment: Actually... I didn't think about that! I'll try to ask there! Thanks!!

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using (when not the latest, 1.8.13, please also try the latest version)? Can you create a small example code (inclusive differences of your Doxyfile from the standard doxyfile).

Answer (score 1):

Apostrophes in code comments must be encoded with the correct glyph for doxygen to parse it correctly. This seems particularly true for the `SOURCE_TOOLTIPS` popups. The correct glyph is `\u2019`, standing for [RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Unicode). If the keyboard you are using is not providing this glyph, you may write a temporary symbol (e.g. `'`) and batch replace it afterwards with an unicode capable auxiliary tool, for example: `perl -pC -e "s/'/\x{2019}/g" < infile > outfile`. Hope it helps.

Comment: I think this is not necessary, doxygen can use for e.g. the Right Single quote: &rsquo; (see doxygen documentation chapter "HTML commands").

Comment: Regarding the apostrophe the OP asks for one can use (the doxygen extension) &apos;

Comment: "Apostrophes in code comments must be encoded with the correct glyph" Huh? What? So if I comment out a piece of code I must batch-process my sources in order to please Doxygen? And if I uncomment it back, I need to batch-process it again? What if my code contains both ASCII apostrophe and Unicode quotation mark? This is beyond silly.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the answer from ramkinobit, this is not necessary, doxygen can use for e.g. the Right Single quote: `&rsquo;` (see doxygen documentation chapter ["HTML commands"](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/htmlcmds.html)).

Regarding the apostrophe the OP asks for one can use (the doxygen extension) `&apos;` (see also doxygen documentation chapter ["HTML commands"](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/htmlcmds.html))).

There was a double 'HTML escape' in doxygen resulting in the behavior as observed for the single quote i.e. displaying `&#39;`.

I've just pushed a proposed patch to github (pull request 784, https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/784).

EDIT 07/07/2018 (alternative) patch has been integrated in main branch on github.